# Barra Equity Risk Model Methodology

Tags: equities, risk-models

I am interested in learning about the Barra's Equity risk model methodology. When I google, this is the first file that comes up: http://www.alacra.com/alacra/help/barra_handbook_US.pdf

However, it looks outdated and I am wondering if there is a newer one that is freely available online.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think anybody will be willing to share the methodologies even if they had them. But I do think you will get answers if you ask more specific questions.

Comment: Barra is now owned by MSCI. You can download the methodology of their latest risk models from their website (if you're a client).

Comment: @J-F oh so the models are for clients only?